# How To Determine Which Unit Test Covered a Function or Method

Tags: python, unit-testing, code-coverage, pytest

From a Python perspective, how can one determine the unit test(s) which covered a function or method, or generally any line of code that was hit by a test in the suite by the test runner? It seems reasonable that this information should be at hand given the coverage tools know the specific code that was hit, but I cannot find any way to get at this information (I am using `py.test` as my test runner with the `coverage` and `pytest-cov` modules).

One approach I have found is to just put a `pdb.set_trace` call into the code, but it would be really helpful if I could find a more elegant way that didn't require modifying the code under test.

Comment: How well organised are your tests? Could you run subsets to see which invoked a particular line?

Comment: I've been using nose to do test code coverage.  ```nosetests --with-coverage --cover-tests```

Comment: They are organized well, but with a collection of thousands of tests, it's a problem I run into on occasion.

Comment: I am specifically using `py.test`. Does `nose` have this ability out of the box? It seems like the `--cover-tests` flag just includes the tests themselves in the report, which is different that what I am looking for here.

Comment: As far as I can see, the only way to do this would be to run narrower subsets of your tests to pin down which are calling the line - in general, coverage tools are set up to tell you whether a line's getting called, not from where.

Comment: I see there's also http://testmon.org/, but not sure if that's really an answer to this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coverage.py doesn't yet provide this feature, but there's an open ticket where we are kicking around ideas: https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/issues/170

To read the old history of this issue, check out [the old ticket](https://bitbucket.org/ned/coveragepy/issues/170/show-who-tests-what) (in the BitBucket tracker)

Comment: Thank you for the link. I will keep an eye on the progress!

Comment: Coverage.py now provides this feature: https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201810/who_tests_what_is_here.html

Answer (score 3):

[Smother](https://github.com/chrisbeaumont/smother) is a wrapper utility around coverage.py that measures code coverage separately for each test in a test suite. Its main features include:

- Fast and reliable coverage tracking using coverage.py.
- Ability to lookup which tests visit an arbitrary section of your application code.
- Ability to convert version control diffs into a subset of affected tests to rerun.

It supports py.test and nose.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check these out.

Comment: I found that installing Smother changed the path loading behavior or py.test; this shoudln't impact anyone doing normal python packaging, but it did effect some odd-ball vendor-straight-jacketed test cases. bewarned

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this code is still functional in the current ecosystem (in particular current coverage version and nose / nose 2 plugin APIs), but the the figleaf-sections plugin from the `figleaf` package provides this feature.

http://darcs.idyll.org/~t/projects/figleaf/doc/

If I recall, it was a nice proof of concept and I'm sure useful, but I think there were a few rough edges, I'd love it if somebody picked up the idea and really made it work smoothly!